# jquery masonry breaks(stacks images) in chrome/safari but only on first load

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

It seems that when I try to load the page, all the images are stacked on top of one another. But if you were to click a link which takes you to the same page (like the home link) then masonry kicks in. So I think masonry is loading too early, like before jquery readies the page or something.

Here my jquery call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#image_roll_container').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.box'
    });

....
```

Here's the page in question:

http://ratattoos.com/

it works just fine in firefox and IE8.

Comment: Please add a screenshot -- your link is broken.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

looks like I needed a plugin called imagesLoaded in order for the Monsry script to work properly with the likes of chrome and safari

Comment: How to use it? or initialize it with Masonry ?

Comment: $('#masonry').imagesLoaded( function() {
  // images have loaded and you can init masonry
});

Answer (score 20):

I've managed to fix this problem with the following tweak:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('img').load(function(){
            $(".content_photo").masonry();
        });
        $(".content_photo").masonry();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

Tried everything suggested in this thread, nothing worked, then found this:

```
$(window).load(function(){   $('#content').masonry(); });
```

Works fine now, found it here:
https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/35

Original post author:
https://github.com/desandro

Answer (score 5):

You are correct about the imagesLoaded.  It was working fine in Firefox but stacking in Chrome/Safari.

Here is the link https://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html#imagesloaded

Code:

```
var $container = $('#container');

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.box'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across this issue.  To fix it, I utilized the img width and height attributes.  The issue resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, if you know the image heights, is to assign them in the CSS before you load Masonry, then the layout is faster than waiting for the images.  This method works if, for example, all your images are the same size.  Then your site will still load quickly on slow connections, like mobile.

I posted a bit of script for alternative method here:
http://instancia.net/loading-jquery-masonry-on-mobile/

If you use this script, edit the numbers to match yours.

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox and on my iPad 2 masonry was working fine but in chrome and safari on OS X the elements were overlapping/stacking on page load and until a window resize even happen. After digging in the code of jquery.masonry.js I found that I can trigger a resize() right after creating the masonry so that all elements rearrange properly. Now everything is working fine.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var $container = $('#container');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry({
    itemsSelector: '.thumbnail',
    isFitWidth: true
    }).resize();
}); 
})
```

all of the other solutions: (window).load, setting width & height in CSS and on img attributes, etc, just didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It needs heights in these browsers to display correctly like Jennifer said. I use php's getimagesize() function to get the height and width of the images. Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        var container = document.querySelector('#masonry');
        var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
            itemSelector: '.item',
            "columnWidth": 200,
        });
        $('.item img').load(function(){
                var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
                itemSelector: '.item',
                "columnWidth": 200,
            });
        })
</script>
```

Comment: Please only use the english language.

Answer (score 0):

if use $('img').load(function() F5(refesh) => error

New Methods:

```js
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
  if ($('.masonry-wrap').length) {
    $('.masonry-wrap')
    .css('max-width', $(window).width());
  }
});
$(window).on('load', function() {
  if ($('.masonry-wrap').length) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.masonry').masonry({
        columnWidth: 0,
        itemSelector: '.grid-item'
      });
    }, 1);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="masonry-wrap">
  <div class="masonry">
    <div class="grid-item">...</div>
    <div class="grid-item">...</div>
    ....
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "load" event will trigger for every image in the DOM, this is overkill. You need to update the layout of the masonry when the last image in the DOM loads. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // init the masonry on document ready event;
    // at this point the images are not loaded so the layout will break UNLESS you set up the correct values for the "width" and "height" attributes of the img tags
    $('.content_photo').masonry();

    // to make sure the layout will not break apart we update the masonry layout just after the last image from the DOM was loaded
    var total_images = $('img').length;
    var counter = 1;
    $('img').load(function() {
        if(counter == total_images) {
            alert('the last image in the DOM was loaded. now we can update the masonry layout');
            $('.content_photo').masonry('layout');
        }
        counter++;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the reverse problem as described: first load worked fine in Mac OS X Safari, but changing the grid with all new items caused them all to stack in the top left corner. Further, waiting for ready event and setting CSS height & width on our elements didn't fix it.

On our site, we have categories of data that display in the masonry grid, and only one category shows at a time. A user could switch the category at any time and trigger an AJAX request to load in the new data. In latest Safari (9.1, 10) and browsers like Chrome, we could simply do this when changing the category to swap in all new elements:

```
    // domData is HTML string from the server
    // IMJS is our global variable that we use for globals and lookups
    $("#divTemplateCategoryName").after(domData); // insert new HTML
    var elementsToAdd = $(".grid-item-template-info"); //select the elements
    IMJS.MasonryGrid.masonry('addItems', elementsToAdd); // tell masonry to add them
    IMJS.MasonryGrid.masonry('layout'); // tell masonry to layout again
```

However, in some versions of Safari that wouldn't work, and we had to do this instead:

```
    // domData is HTML string from the server
    // IMJS is our global variable that we use for globals and lookups
    IMJS.MasonryGrid.masonry('destroy'); // destroy the grid
    $("#divTemplateCategoryName").after(domData); // insert new HTML
    InitMasonry(); // re-do our entire masonry init
```

Because I don't have the time to track down every browser version that might be affected by this bug, I switched to the latter method for all browsers.